# .gitlab-ci.yml not found in this commit

Tags: gitlab

When I take a *mergeRequest* in **GitLab**, there is a compile error with description:

> CI build failed for 4a0b9b43 , view Details：.gitlab-ci.yml not 
>                                                       found in this commit.

But I have sync with the destination branch and compile succeed on native, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You must place the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to the root directory of a project first. If you want to cross-reference other CI configuration locally or from somewhere (GitLab instance required to install on remote locations), you must use the `include` tag

### [How-to](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#include-examples)

> Please check your GL instance version first before you are using `include`. Compare your instance version with the minimum version required from the documentation. If you need to upgrade, back up everything and run an update. It should take hours before you can go back into business.

To cross-reference CI config files locally, use the `include:local`. Make sure they are on the same branch. If that is on other branch, use `ref`.

```
include:
 - local: '/templates/.gitlab-ci-template.yml'
```

In case you want to cross-reference CI config files somewhere within the instance, use

```
include:
  - project: 'my-group/my-project'
    file: '/templates/.gitlab-ci-template.yml'

  # You can also specify ref, with the default being the head of the object.

  - project: 'my-group/my-project'
    ref: master # Git branch
    file: '/templates/.gitlab-ci-template.yml'

  - project: 'my-group/my-project'
    ref: v1.0.0 # Git tag
    file: '/templates/.gitlab-ci-template.yml'

  - project: 'my-group/my-project'
    ref: 787123b47f14b552955ca2786bc9542ae66fee5b # Git SHA
    file: '/templates/.gitlab-ci-template.yml'
```

If you prefer to use CI config templates shipped with the instance, use `include:template`. [Check the GitLab's template collection](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/tree/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/) for more details.

```
include:
  - template: Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml
```

If deployed outside the instance borders, like `GitLab.com`, use `include:remote`.

```
include:
  - remote: 'https://gitlab.com/awesome-project/raw/master/.gitlab-ci-template.yml'
```

### Examples

The first example was derived from [GitLab's CI config file for GitLab EE (`gitlab-org/gitlab`)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml).

```
image: "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-build-images:ruby-2.6.3-golang-1.12-git-2.24-lfs-2.9-chrome-73.0-node-12.x-yarn-1.16-postgresql-9.6-graphicsmagick-1.3.33"

stages:
  - sync
  - prepare
  - quick-test
  - test
  - post-test
  - review-prepare
  - review
  - qa
  - post-qa
  - notification
  - pages

variables:
  RAILS_ENV: "test"
  NODE_ENV: "test"
  SIMPLECOV: "true"
  GIT_DEPTH: "20"
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: "none"
  GET_SOURCES_ATTEMPTS: "3"
  KNAPSACK_RSPEC_SUITE_REPORT_PATH: knapsack/report-master.json
  FLAKY_RSPEC_SUITE_REPORT_PATH: rspec_flaky/report-suite.json
  BUILD_ASSETS_IMAGE: "false"
  ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xms256m -Xmx256m"
  ELASTIC_URL: "http://elastic:changeme@elasticsearch:9200"

after_script:
  - date

include:
  - local: .gitlab/ci/cache-repo.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: .gitlab/ci/cng.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: .gitlab/ci/docs.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: .gitlab/ci/frontend.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: .gitlab/ci/global.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: .gitlab/ci/memory.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: .gitlab/ci/notifications.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: .gitlab/ci/pages.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: .gitlab/ci/qa.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: .gitlab/ci/reports.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: .gitlab/ci/rails.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: .gitlab/ci/review.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: .gitlab/ci/setup.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: .gitlab/ci/dev-fixtures.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: .gitlab/ci/test-metadata.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: .gitlab/ci/yaml.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: .gitlab/ci/releases.gitlab-ci.yml
```

You can see more examples [on the `.gitlab-ci.yml` reference in the GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#include-examples).